# Generate type options in a string

Tags: typescript

I have a type

```
MemberRole = 'EMPLOYEE' | 'ADMINISTRATOR' | 'OWNER'
```

and I have a middleware that accepts a string with this format:
`role:EMPLOYEE|ADMINISTRATOR`

what I want is to be able to generate possible strings from this MemberRole:

the closes i got was:

```
type MemberRoleString = 
 | `role:${MemberRole}`
 | `role:${MemberRole}|${MemberRole}`
 | `role:${MemberRole}|${MemberRole}|${MemberRole}`
```

but here I could have some roles duplications `role:EMPLOYEE|EMPLOYEE|EMPLOYEE` or
`role:ADMINISTRATOR|EMPLOYEE|EMPLOYEE`

is there a way to prevent this?

Ps: order is not relevant
Ps2: MemberRole has 7 roles

Comment: Generally I would use an enum instead of a union. Also, *why* do you need that? I'm struggling to think of a reason you could possibly need a glommed together string *type*.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Do you disallow any duplicates at all? Or is it only the last two?

Comment: @catgirlkelly AFAICT the OP wants all the members of the union as a single delimited string type `type Desired = "role:EMPLOYEE|ADMINISTRATOR|OWNER"` although as I said I don't understand what the point could possibly be.

Comment: Using something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJqZrm), it's possible to generate all strings with no duplicates.

Comment: "MemberRole has 7 roles" means that a specific type would be a union of 13,699 (approximately ×7!)  elements.  This could be generated programmatically but it could be taxing on the compiler.  And introduce just another role or two to that and the union becomes too big for the compiler to represent.  Do you want to pursue this approach, or would you be okay with a generic helper type/function that just *checks* a string?

Comment: [This code](https://tsplay.dev/weXkdW) is what happens when you generate the union programmatically.  Is that what you want?  Please test against your use cases and get back to me with whether or not you'd like this written up as an answer, or whether this type generates unions too big for your purposes or if there's some other problem.

Comment: this is what i was looking to @jcalz, but as your comment says "taxing on the compiler" i think i wouldn't follow this approach and will use a function to work arround it

Comment: So then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnaDdw) would be how I'd make a helper generic type that just validates a string at compile time instead of generating every possible valid string in advance.  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: @jcalz your example code definitely answers the question. Consider posting it with comments.

Comment: @ZeroDistraction Ideally the OP of the question would reply to me one way or the other first, so I don't spend my time and effort writing up an answer (I tend to be fairly, uh, *thorough* in my answers) if my approach doesn't suffice.

Comment: @jcalz fair. looking forward to it. cheers.